# How to determine what data is included on the Y axis when creating charts in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba to create charts with dynamic ranges, and excel is automatically choosing if the row or columnn of data is used to create the "series" for the charts based on relative dimensions of the dataset (see images). How do I pre determine that the y values of a "series" are always data in the same row, never in the same column.
![incorrect]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/097PK.jpg
![Correct]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSPco.jpg

First post, apologies for incorrect formatting, etc

Confirmed that the data range is correct. Almost 100% sure it's because in the incorrect scenario, there are more rows than columns, so it defaults to using the values from one column instead of values from one row.

```
Set rng = Selection

    Sheet9.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlLine, , , WorksheetFunction.max(500, 1.7 * lcol)).Select

    With ActiveChart
        .SetSourceData Source:=rng
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheet10.Range(Sheet10.Cells(5, 3), Sheet10.Cells(5, lcol2))

        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)

        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Equipment Utilization (Weekly)"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Date"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Utilization"
        .HasLegend = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).Select
        Selection.TickLabels.Orientation = xlUpward

        .Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1

    End With
```

Comment: Why do you need `SetSourceData` AND `FullSeriesCollection(1)`? Why not just set your chart range with `SetSourceData` and be done with it?

Comment: That what I got when I recorded the macro, X axis labels are not immediately next to the data that is being plotted (see either image)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.range("A5:E15"), PlotBy:=xlColumns`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.setsourcedata

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. As I don't have your data, you may still need to modify this a little.  Also, you should use a xyscatter plot (that is what I used). Finally, it is bad practice to use selection and select when making code. Try to modify it to not use these.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Dim intI As Integer
    Dim strSheet As String
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim lCol2 As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRow2 As Long

    strSheet = "Sheet1"
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheet)

    Set rng = sht.Range("D5")
    lCol = rng.Column
    lCol2 = sht.Range(sht.Cells(rng.Row, _
                      sht.Columns.Count).Address).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lRow = rng.Row + 3 '3 is the offset from D5!
    lRow2 = sht.Range(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, _
                      rng.Column).Address).End(xlUp).Row

    sht.Shapes.AddChart2 -1, xlXYScatterLines, , , _
                         WorksheetFunction.Max(500, 1.7 * lCol)

    With sht.Shapes(sht.Shapes.Count).Chart
        '.SetSourceData Source:=Rng
        For intI = lCol To lCol2
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
                       sht.Range(sht.Cells(rng.Row, lCol), sht.Cells(rng.Row, lCol2))
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = _
                       sht.Range(sht.Cells(lRow, intI), sht.Cells(lRow2, intI))
        Next intI

        .SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis
        .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis

        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Equipment Utilization (Weekly)"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Date"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Utilization"
        .HasLegend = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = xlUpward

        '.Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        '.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1

    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set sht = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response IAmNerd2000, the loop creating a new data series clears things up. And thanks for the "best coding practice" feedback!